# What's the mechanism of locking access to selected applications in Android?

Tags: android, security

I'm trying to find out how applications like [Perfect App Protector](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.morrison.applocklite&feature=search_result) or [Smart Applock Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.thinkyeah.smartlockfree&feature=search_result) work.

What mechanism is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These applications use a service to monitor whether a new application is trying to launch or not.

It can be done in several ways. If running application matched with the configured application then it is sent back to the background by the service and may ask for lock code, password as you configured earlier. If it matches then you will get the application on the foreground. Otherwise it kills the process from being executed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Is there any other way of monitoring new application launching then cyclic checking of running processes?

Comment: You can try ACTION_PAKCAGE_RESTARTED intent